# Plotting the graph of $x(t)$ when the graph of $x'(t)=f(x)$ is given

Tags: calculus

[image]I am not sure how to present this problem clearly. Please feel free to suggest edits to this problem so that this will be useful to someone who will look at this in the future.

Here's my question:

Suppose $x'(t)=f(x)$ and suppose the graph of $f(x)$ is given. How can we draw the graph of $x(t)$ using the graph of $f(x).$

What I have tried so far: I have found equilibrium points and their stabilities using the graph of $f(x).$ But I don't know how this can be used when plotting $x(t).$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I'm missing something... Why not just plot the integral/antiderivative?

Comment: @ÉricoPatto it sounds like they only have the graph of $f(x)$, not a formula.

Comment: Of course, If you are in a region where the derivative is negative (resp. positive), the function is decreasing (resp. increasing), but it's impossible to reconstruct **precisely** the shape "by hand"...

Comment: @DMcMor, OK, but for any $x$, one could find an approximate value of $\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$ from the graph of $f$.

Comment: @JeanMarie What do you mean by "resp. " ?  is it abbreviation of "respectively" ?

Comment: Yes, it is a classical abbreviation.

Comment: I only have the graph of f(x). I just added that as an image. Could someone please explain how I can do this as accurately as possible. I’m not interested in this particular  question. I would really appreciate a more general approach or an explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cut the graph in as small slices as is reasonable for you to follow. Then instead of a graph you will have a series of bars. However, definite integrals, and this is the only one you can draw, differ by a constant from each other.

Now

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = F(b)-F(a)$$

So if $F(a)=0$ then you have

$$\int_{a,F(a)=0}^{b} f(x) dx = F(b)$$

so you can ignore this at first as after you draw an integral you can just shift the axis appropriately to the location you want to have.

So, in order to draw a graph you just stack bars (respecting the direction of each bar) and moving as you go along to the right, bar by bar. It is very easy to do this using compass and triangle albeit tedious.

[image]

Notice that your choice of step size will affect the final scale of y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT. You can use the second derivative (approximate and in green color below) to have an approximate shape of your function (in black color below). Unfortunately, I believe it is not possible to find out the corresponding market points, two extremunms (maximum and minimum) and three inflection ones because you don't have the analytic expression of your derivative $x'(t)$ but only the graph.

[image]